# Unable to fetch from coreData using Predicate as String?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am unable to fetch data using a string as a direct argument to NSPredicate. Is there any difference between these two,

```
//Working case
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "role == %@","GK")
```

In the above case, I am able to fetch the data with the predicate.

```
//Not Working
predicateString = String(format:"role == %@","GK")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: predicateString)
```

Here I am unable to fetch the data.

The only difference between the above two cases is that I'm using a String variable to define the predicate. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the %@ is replaced with a string variable when instantiating a NSPredicate the string variable is automatically surrounded by quotes so in your example the predicate becomes `role == 'GK'`

If you want to use String(format:...) you need to add the quotes yourself but in my opinion it's better to use NSPredicate(format:...) directly instead to avoid issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

Format of `NSPredicate` is as following, where it expects a format, and format contains equaliser.

```
    NSPredicate(format: <String>, <args: CVarArg...>)
```

---

```
    let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "role == %@", "GK")
```

Here, if you will check the `predicate1.predicateFormat`, then you will get:

**"role == \"GK\""**,

which equilise role with string `"GK"` and return result in `array`.

**But for,**

```
    let predicateString = String(format:"role == %@","GK")
    let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: predicateString)
```

You replaced the equaliser with simple string, which fails to return anything. You can check with `predicate1.predicateFormat` which will return:

**"role == GK"**

Here you can use `"role == 'GK'"` if you want to use string.

Hope it will help.

Comment: "role == GK" won't work either. I should have gone for role == 'GK'. Thanks.

Comment: @fAiSaL, thats what I explained. `"role == GK"` wont work. `role == "GK"` or in string you can say, `role == 'GK'` will work.